# Windows claims Im connected

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista

I'm using Windows Vista x64 and an external wireless card. Windows claims I have local and internet connections. [image: connected]

However no websites will load. 
Skype claims it's connecting and appears gray. However from time to time I will see that people are online (with offline icons haha). And I did successfully msg some people and received msgs from them.

This is the first time I've seen this behavior. What is going on?

Just in case this is my wireless card:

(wireless-card) ...http://ravetek-wholesale.com/161-278-large/tp-link-150mbps-mini-wireless-n-usb-adapter-tl-wn723n.jpg (link broke became advertizing instead)

Additional details:

- I have been connected successfully for weeks before.
- I can see the wireless networks and connect to them fine.
- I tried restarting the wireless router I'm connecting to.
- I have tried shutting down the firewall but it did not do anything.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your computer, router, and modem? Any of these three could cause issues like what you are experiencing. I would also check for updates

Comment: @David yes to all. And i dont think its the modem since everyone else in the household has no problems with the internet

Comment: Could you try ejecting the wireless card, then reconnecting it?

Comment: is your firewall configured correctly?

Comment: @ratchetfreak, if he can turn the firewall off and continue to experience the issue, the firewall cannot be the issue. Good thinking though.

Comment: Has anything changed recently on your computer or on the network? Any new software or hardware? Have you recently added a new device to the network?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your TCP/IP Stack?

```
ipconfig /all
```

will tell you all the info your card is getting from your DHCP. After that try

```
nslookup www.google.com
```

and see what you get, if you have an IP address you might be connected but you might be having DNS trouble.

if **nslookup** doesn't respond but you have an IP Address try setting your DNS servers to opendns servers and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try ejecting and reconnecting the USB wireless USB adapter. If this fixes the issue, there was just something weird going on with the card.

Another troubleshooting step would be to temporarily connect your computer to the router using a known good Ethernet cable. If this fixes the issue, you may need to res-install the wireless card drivers/software and check for Windows Updates.

Another possible fix (doesn't usually work, but in rare cases I have had luck with) having Windows try to repair it. Go to your wireless adapter. A way of getting to your wireless adapter is:

1. Click start -> right-click on Network -> click Properties -> and click "Manage wireless networks". That way of getting there works with Windows 7 if you have the start bar setup to show network. I'm not sure if that will work for Vista.
2. Right-click on the adapter having issues, and click "Diagnose". Again this is for Windows 7,but I don't think Windows Vista is very different in this aspect. This will run a wizard to attempt to fix the issue.